# How to copy or project uvs & (data block) to another object

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, linked-data, data-blocks

How to copy or project uvs & (data block) to another object? to use the same UV map in other objects

**How i do this ?**

> Maybe you want to work on your object until it satisfies the lowpoly lod level, then unwrap and duplicate, and add a subdivide modifier with the option 'subdivide uv' off. This way all you object will have the same uv layer – Yvain Mar 30 '16 at 11:22

[image: Example]

when I try to do this I did not have a good result, and I do not copy anything, or nothing in a correct way, I do not copy the SEAMS, and when I copy the UVs, this appears
[You can try the "transfer data" tool (the modifier also works, sometimes...).](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53694/58715)
[image]

Documenting readings and research
interesting, it seems that I'm not the only one who has had problems with this! [image: Documenting readings and research]